# Problem with Unicode in LaTeX editor (LEd)

Tags: unicode, languages, input-encodings

I have an UTF-8, polish text in .tex file. When I open it with my LEd (LaTeX editor), it shows ok (all characters can be seen). But when I try to compile it, I get error:

```
Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc) in inputencoding `utf8'.
```

I have to copy the text, cut it and paste to Notepad++, change (not convert!) encoding from UTF8 to ANSI (the polish characters will be missed and replaces with some random characters). Than copy it again and paste to LEd (in that editor, characters display bad also). But now I can compile my pdf and in it, the encoding is right again.

**Is there a way** to set encoding in the way I will see characters in LEd propertly **and** I will be able to compile it **and** I will get good characters in pdf?

The begging of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{txfonts}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: I don't think LEd supports UTF-8. I guess it's time to change editor.

Comment: As @egreg says, LEd is not really 'up to date': there has not been a release for several years. I'd suggest looking over [our list of IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) which includes details such as UTF-8 support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At http://www.latexeditor.org/news.html, a news post dated October 2009 reads:

> Currently we are working on:
>
> - [...]
> - adding support for Unicode and UTF-7, UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 encodings,
> - [...]

So support for Unicode reportedly is in the works.

However, the last release of LEd dates back to as far as October 2009; that's more than four years ago, at the time of writing this answer. According to the [same page](http://www.latexeditor.org/news.html), previous releases of LEd used to take place at much shorter intervals, on an annual/biannual basis.

It's fair to assume that maintenance of the editor has stopped. In all likelihood, LEd is now in the doldrums. As suggested by egreg and Joseph Wright in their comments, it may be time for you to switch to a TeX editor that offers Unicode support. See [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) to guide your decision.